# Manually Controlling DFP Ad Selection and Display

Tags: google-dfp

We want to add to our existing DFP enabled site an alphabetical listing of our advertisers, via custom creatives for this list, and by taking advantage of the existing working custom targeting. We would like to do this entirely using DFP as it already has the advertiser reports and we want to incorporate the impression count and click-through rates for these listings in the existing reports to our advertisers.

In pseudo-code it would be something like:

```
googletag.setTargeting( “key”, “value” );                      
SessionStore<Array> adList = googletag.getAds();
SessionStore<int> offset = 0;

// optionally sort adList by Advertiser Name, or other metadata
for ( int i = 0; i < 10; i++ ) {
    var adItem = adList[offset + i];
    document.write( ‘<div id=”ad_id_’ + adList.adID + ‘”’ );
    googletag.defineSlot( networkIDplus, [custom creative size], ‘ad_id_” + adList.adID );
}
// store remainder for ‘next’ page
offset = 10;
```

This way if there were 18 custom creative for the advertisers, we could display 10 on the first page, and then the remaining 8 on a second view.

Looking at the DFP API – it appears that is designed for ad management only, and not display. Looking at the Google Publisher Tag API, it does not support targeting specific ads for display or returning lists of ads.

As an alternative, using a page of 10 tags and then a ‘refresh’ does not make sense as we would not be able to guarantee that the listing is clean and in order without duplicates.

Is there something I’m missing from Google/DFP or does anyone have a workaround so that we can paginate ads and control which ads are display where and when?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

I only have a work around I'm afraid...

To get a specific creative to display in a specific space all the time, you'd have to create an Ad Unit for each slot on the UI and traffic a single lineitem + creative through it.
(You could dynamically assign the Ad Unit ID but that's about as elegant as it gets).

1: Create an ad unit, (override to deselect adsense just to be safe)
2: Create a line item with a single creative and assign to the adUnit
type = sponsorship or house
Goal = 100% impressions

Pretty high level description let me know if you need more detail.

Comment: Dave - thanks for your work-around, it makes sense. And its a neat idea. 

But as I see it implemented it would require that we keep a list elsewhere of each ad and its respective slots, along with tags, etc pretty much duplicating what DFP already has and is doing for us. And that duplication is exactly what I'm trying to avoid.